# Why not "I opened him the door"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

In actions that involve another person, we can structure sentences like the following examples:

> I drove **him** home.
>
> I cooked **him** a meal.
>
> I gave **him** a spoon.
>
> I threw **him** the ball.

I'm not sure of the name of this grammar pattern, but the use of the pronoun "him" is simply a shortening of "for him" or "to him" or "at him", depending.

Is there a reason why we can't (or at least, don't) say:

> I **opened/closed** him the door.

to mean "I opened/closed the door for him"?  Is there a grammar rule, or is it just not idiomatic?

Comment: @Lawrence  Nifty, thanks.  Is there some way to search for these without knowing the specific text of the title?  I tried to search various key phrases but none of the suggested answers came even close.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - I only saw your comment when coming here via a link someone posted [at ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118777/should-i-write-i-opened-him-the-door-after-i-had-made-him-open-the-door#comment239649_118777). Remembering a similar question from prior browsing helps with the search. :P

Comment: Unfortunately, searching is more art than science - maybe even more lottery than art. However, there are some things you can try, such as typing *is:question* in the search box at the top-right corner of the page to search only in the question text, not answers (cuts down on duplicates in the search results), and typing tags in square brackets (e.g. *[grammar]*).